# Why does my .Net Core console application have the wrong build target?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I created a .NET Core Console Application through MS VS. After building the application and navigating to the build directory there is a .dll file, not a .exe.

Why has this happened and how do I fix it?

PS: the Class Library project also generates .dll.

Comment: Class Library projects will INDEED generate only .dll

Comment: yes, I agree - I just say that Class library project generate expected binary type, instead of console project type.

Comment: This has already been answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37393124/616304

Comment: I can confirm that if I go to `/bin/debug/netcoreapp1.0/`, I have a dll.  When I jump into the next folder, `/win7-x64/`, I have an exe (this is for a web project).  Do you have any other folders to search through?