# Is it possible to compile a C# program from Visual Studio for running on Mac?

Tags: c#, windows, macos, visual-studio, compilation

I've written a C# program on Visual Studio 2015, and I would like to be able to run it on Mac, and possible Linux. Is this possible?
I realise that when compiling a project from Xamarin on Mac, it's exported as a **.exe**, so would running the .exe compiled on Windows be runnable on Mac?
And if not, how would I make it be?
It doesn't matter if a single .exe can't be cross platform, so long as I can compile for both OS's.
Also, it doesn't matter if it actually is a .exe, so long as it can be run.
Would I be required to actually compile my C# project *on* a mac?

Comment: With **mono** run-time installed on your Mac, you may run exe files generated by Visual Studio. However, you may need to introduce in your c# code some conditional compile directives to adress compatibility issues.

Comment: Go to http://dot.net and you will see what's recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run the exe in Mac by using mono:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono --runtime=v4.0 [path-to-your-exe]
```

Comment: Although I can't test this right now, it definitely looks right!

Comment: @MrHinsh how exactly would I do this?

Comment: @JacobGarby test Mono and then you will see how much trouble there can be. Already tons of posts around the internet on compatibility.

Comment: @MrHinsh seriously that's .NET Core, a new platform, not .NET Framework nor Mono.

Comment: And if you write in .NET Core using C# the resultant code will work on any platform: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390798/build-exe-file-in-net-core-rc2/37393124

Comment: @JacobGarby - I strongly suggest that you install Mono on your Windows computer to test/adapt your code to the Mono framework, before further adaptation to Mac environlment.