# Publish ONE executable file

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-1.1

Is there a possibility to publish .NET Core Console Application as single file (no matter if it's EXE or DLL)?

I am using .NET Core 1.1 but I am elastic to port my project to another version.

Comment: You should be able to do something with satellite assemblies

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390798/build-exe-file-in-net-core-rc2?rq=1

Comment: I tried to follow instructions from answer you linked, but no effects. After publish I get very long list of DLL's (not only one).

Comment: @mankers What is meant by "elastic?" Do you mean you are hoping or planning to port your project to another version?

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin Not exactly, I am launching new project and it's currently at research stage.

Comment: @mankers What is meant by the word "elastic" in your question?

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin Elastic, flexible, changeable. I was looking for solution applicable to .NET Core 1.1. However, if you gave me a ready solution working on .NET Core 2.0, I would consider porting my project (with very tiny SLoC) to .NET Core 2.0. It's gonna be very simple app and the only requirement is to be written it in .NET Core *.*.

Comment: @mankers I don't believe there are going to be many breaking changes in .NET Core 2.0. I am still working on .NET Core 1.1, but my understanding is that it is pretty much backwards compatible. CoreRT is what I think you are looking for to get a single executable file as Martin Ullrich had suggested. https://github.com/dotnet/corert

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible because:

- **portable** applications still need at least a `runtimeconfig.json` to tell the host (`dotnet` / `dotnet.exe`) which shared runtime to use. Even if you IL-Merge all your managed code into a single dll, this file is still required. The host also expects a `deps.json` expressing the dependencies of the application.
- **self-contained** applications rely on building a `.dll` + `.deps.json` and copying over content from runtime-specific NuGet packages. This also includes native libraries that are searched for [by file name](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/e4197bc03d599f642b75983431d3ebad265c2588/src/corehost/common/pal.h#L75-L85).

The [CoreRT project](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) aims to compile a .NET Core application to a single native binary using ahead-of-time compilation but is still in development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post-release process to wrap up the release into a self executing archive (such as [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) or [IExpress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-ieak/iexpress-wizard-for-win-server)).

The archive includes all your release files, and can be configured to launch a specific application file after extraction.

This would be a good fit for installers, where you want to only provide a single file but don't want a bootstrapped installer.

## Caveats:

- By default, most self extracting archives will extract to a temporary directory, and clean up (i.e., delete) the directory after the application terminates.
- Start up times will, naturally, be slower due to the extraction process - larger release, longer extraction time.
- OS specific self extracting archives may be required for cross-platform compatibility.