# Generating .NET Core Console App .exe in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application

(I am using Visual Studio 2017)

I started a small console application (I created a .NET Core application), then I wanted to build the .exe file. 
But all I get is .dll files and there isn't any .exe file.

Can you help me please ? what do I change in Visual Studios settings, to have an .exe file in my correct directory for my console application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build .exe file in .NET Core RC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390798/build-exe-file-in-net-core-rc2)

Comment: The process is now a bit different for .NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact .NET Core by default generates only `dll` files that can be run with `dotnet`:

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

If you want to publish the app as a self-contained `exe`, you have to right-click the project in **Solution Explorer**, select **Publish** and then choose the self-contained option and either **win-x86** or **win-x64**. This will generate a platform specific, architecture specific `exe`.

Check out [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/) that goes into more detail about this process.

Comment: The publish option for a console app is pretty handy. Thanks!